# Controlador de volume

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho um script para o controlador, e ele estipula um valor, e esse valor eu queria colocar como volume. É possível realizar isso? Abaixo irei mostrar onde eu quero que fique o valor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new WHMSonic({
        path : "http://gerador.hostseries.com.br/HostSeriesPlayer.swf",
        source : "http://192.99.181.93:9960",
        volume : 50,
        autoplay : true,
        width: 372,
        height: 60,
        twitter : "http://twitter.com/HostSeries",
        facebook : "http://facebook.com/HostSeries",
        logo : "http://www.hostseries.com.br",
    });
    </script>
```

E aqui está o meu script:

OBS: O valor dele vai para a `<div id="valor"></div>`

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
var slider = document.querySelector('.controlar .bola');
var limites = document.querySelector('.controlar').getBoundingClientRect();
var valor = document.getElementById('valor');
// arrastar slider
var ativo = false;
var offset = 0;

function toggleAtivo(e) {
    if (e.target != slider) return;
    ativo = (e.type == 'mousedown');
    var sliderPosition = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    offset = sliderPosition - e.pageX;
}
window.addEventListener('mousedown', toggleAtivo);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', toggleAtivo);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (!ativo) return;
    var position = e.pageX + offset;
    if (position < limites.left || position > limites.right) return;
    slider.style.left = position + 'px';
    valor.innerHTML = position * limites.width / 100;
});
}//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: Não entendi, qual é o problema de inserir o volume?
http://websiteshotel.com.br/whmsonic/

Comment: O valor não vai pro volume, queria saber como vai.

Comment: Eu não conheço esse `WHMSonic`. Podes fazer um jsFiddle com um exemplo? O que eu acho que será possivel é fazer `var player = new WHMSonic({` e depois usar um método desse plugin para mudar o volume. Tipo `player.setVolume(position * limites.width / 100);`... não digo que o método tenha esse nome, mas imagino que seja algo por aí.

Comment: Eu acho que desse modo que você disse dá certo. Poderia colocar como resposta?

Comment: Você está dizendo que o som não é definido pela variável do player?

Comment: Já verificou nesses link: http://www.whmsonic.com/v2/tutorials/ e http://help.sonicpanel.com/